# Vuex - Model nested modules' dependency

Tags: typescript, vue.js, module, dependencies, vuex

I have a dependency between properties in my app's state that I don't know how to express in Vuex.

The user can log in and then select one of many workspaces to connect to. Obviously, he cannot connect to a workspace if he is not logged in. This dependency of the workspace on the login is what I am having trouble with.

The "brute force" way of making this work is before each access to the workspace data to manually check whether the user is logged in. However, this check is easy to forget, which is why I would like an alternative like this:
If I can nest the workspace as a property of the session, I could force the store's users to check whether the session is present before they access the workspace (e. g. using TypeScript's strict mode).

```
type State = {
  session?: {
    userInfo: {username: string},
    workspaceInfo: {workspaceId: string},
  }
}
```

With a strict setting, TypeScript will warn when accessing `state.session.workspaceInfo`, without having ensured that `session` is defined. This is a solution I'd be happy with.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to represent this in Vuex, because I cannot "nest" a submodule inside the state, nor make a module "optional" in the sense that it might be undefined.

Is there a solution that models this dependency in Vuex?

Answer (score 0):

Just going through a similar issue to this and have trying different things due to lack of apparent documentation on this issue. From experimentation, the following approach seems to work:

```
export interface RootState {
  moduleA: ModuleAState;
  moduleB: ModuleBState;
}

export interface ModuleAState {
  valueA: string;
}

export interface ModuleBState {
 valueB: string;
}
```

This allows you to accessed the namespaced state using `state.moduleA.valueA`